# spring batch and JPA with two databases

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I have spring batch using two databases reader using MySQL and writer using spring h2. So both configured with model and respective repositories.
Even though the model is just the same, read as a list of the model, while writing into another repo with the same kind of model throwing type casting error.
So I have tried n number type casing the objects to save but still throws error.  Your help appreciated.
**Error:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: net.guides.springboot2.springboot2jpacrudexample.model.Employee
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:787) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
```

**ItemReader :**

```
@Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepositoryMYSQL;
        @Override
    public Employee1 read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException
    {
    
        return employeeRepositoryMYSQL.findAll;
    }
```

**Item writer::** - here where the value is coming, but an error pops while saving due to typecasting!

```
 @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository2 employeeRepositoryH2;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Employee2> Employees) throws Exception {
      employeeRepositoryH2.saveAll(Employees);
    }
```

**Model1:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee1 {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "USER_SEQ_GENERATOR")
    private Long id;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private String email_address;
    public Employee1() {
        
    }
    

    @Id
    /* @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE) */
    
    @SequenceGenerator(
          name = "USER_SEQ_GENERATOR",
          sequenceName = "USER_SEQ",
          initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int i) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirst_name()
    {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name)
    {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getLast_name()
    {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name)
    {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public String getEmail_address()
    {
        return email_address;
    }

    public void setEmail_address(String email_address)
    {
        this.email_address = email_address;
    }
```

**Model2:**

```
Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee2 {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "USER_SEQ_GENERATOR")
    private BigInteger id;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private String email_address;
    public Employee2() {
        
    }
    

    @Id
    /* @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE) */
    
    @SequenceGenerator(
          name = "USER_SEQ_GENERATOR",
          sequenceName = "USER_SEQ",
          initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    
    public BigInteger getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(BigInteger id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getFirst_name()
    {
        return first_name;
    }


    public void setFirst_name(String first_name)
    {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }


    public String getLast_name()
    {
        return last_name;
    }


    public void setLast_name(String last_name)
    {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }


    public String getEmail_address()
    {
        return email_address;
    }


    public void setEmail_address(String email_address)
    {
        this.email_address = email_address;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Even though the model is just the same, read as a list of the model, while writing into another repo with the same kind of model throwing type casting error

The model is the same (conceptually the same fields) but the classes are different: `Employee1` and `Employee2`.

In a chunk-oriented step *without* a processor, items returned by the reader are "handed" to the writer in chunks (for bulk updates). This means they must be of the same type. However, that's not a requirement. If read items are not of the same type as written items, an `ItemProcessor` can be used to do the transformation. Data transformation is a [typical use case](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#itemProcessor) for an item processor.

So in your case, you need to add an `ItemProcessor<Employee1, Employee2>` to your step.